# Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed error during EncryptedDataBagItem.load due to supposed regex mismatch

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm bootstrapping a node with a cookbook that worked fine with chef-client as of November, unfortunately the following code:

```
45:  #Configure PostgreSQL cluster -- create pertinent databases, users, and groups based on uploaded, decrypted shell here-document.
47>> here_doc_name = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("database_configs", "tlcworx_#{node["tlcworx_db"]["environment"]}")["filename"]
48:  here_doc_content = Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load("database_configs", "tlcworx_#{node["tlcworx_db"]["environment"]}")["content"]
49:
50:  open("#{node["tlcworx_db"]["tmp_dir"]}/#{here_doc_name}", 'w') { |f| f.puts here_doc_content }
```

Has rendered up the following error that halts the bootstrap:

```
Chef::Exceptions::ValidationFailed: Option data_bag's value {"encrypted_data"=>"PffgOkpIpdoEJO8khrUOUQwqv2/vqrtzOf1U/z/a5xD4KqSH2/CkD1zHndzW\nwJL1\n", "iv"=>"d/kiiPRQWQoKBTU5WF8NPw==\n", "version"=>1, "cipher"=>"aes-256-cbc"} does not match regular expression /^[\-[:alnum:]_]+$/
```

Obviously, I'm supplying the same `--secret-file` as I did back  then via knife CLI argument. Running `knife data bag edit database_configs tlcworx_uat --secret-file /path/to/secret.pem` decrypts the cookbook content appropriately, and doesn't error out. I've never seen this error before, and looking at other instances of this error I see they involve direct CLI operations in which the data bag in question is not named such as [this instance](https://devopsengineer.wordpress.com/2015/02/16/knife-data-bag-from-file-error/). Again, this is only upon bootstrap when a server's chef-client is communicating with the remote chef-server.

I was hoping someone could provide some insight as to what could be causing the error. Chef client version is 12.7.2.

Thanks in advance for any help on the matter!

Comment: This was also reported on the Hangops Slack. It seems to be new in either 12.7 or 12.6.

Comment: I added my email to their signup page. So far nothing has arrived to my inbox. Hopefully I get an invite so I can search for this error. At any rate, if someone finds the answer there I'd love some feedback!

Comment: From Hangops advice I can confirm that adding --bootstrap-version with the version I last used this cookbook succeeds: `knife bootstrap --bootstrap-version 12.5.1 [...]` does work.

Comment: I'm going to be filing this with the chef team here https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/4628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future, we're pretty sure this is a side effect of a bug with `DataBagItem.to_hash` mutating it's data. Will be fixed in the next release of Chef.